# Cross-realm Kerberos/SPNEGO configuration with multiple domain controllers and multiple application servers

Tags: linux, nginx, active-directory, kerberos, spnego

I am currently struggling to scale my one-to-one simple Kerberos/SPNEGO configuration for multi-server environment and looking for some help.

Let's say

- I have two Active Directory domains and two realms `EXAMPLE1.COM` and `EXAMPLE2.COM` associated with them,
- I have multiple domain controllers in both of them (`dc1.example1.com`, `dc2.example1.com` and `dc1.example2.com`, `dc2.example2.com`, respectively),
- I also have two instances of my PHP application deployed on two different servers `app1.example1.com` and `app2.example1.com`, and an NGINX load balancer `lb.example1.com` in front of them.

I've tried to show this configuration on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb6Ls.png).

I want users from both domains be able to send requests to `lb.example1.com`, which in turn should forward them to application servers where the user must be authorized via SPNEGO/Kerberos protocol. For implementing SPNEGO, I am using NGINX compiled with additional `spnego-http-auth-nginx-module`.

My questions are the following:

- Am I right that I must authorize users at `app1.example1.com` and `app2.example1.com`? or, maybe, `lb.example1.com` should be the point of authorization? How can I securely forward information about authorized users to the application servers then?
- How my `/etc/krb5.conf` should look like in this case? Can you provide an example for my configuration?
- How the keytab-files should be generated with `ktpass`? Am I suppose to create a single keytab-file for both `app1.example1.com` and `app2.example1.com` or should it be different files? Should I run `ktpass` on each domain controller? Should I create two different SPNs for both `app1.example1.com` and `app2.example1.com`? map them to different users? In would be nice if you provide the complete set of PowerShell commands that should be executed and specify the domain controllers where they should be executed.

Comment: This is an excellent example of a case where Kerberos should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create two different SPNs for both app1.example1.com and app2.example1.com?

For HTTP auth, the URL determines what SPN the client will look for. (It's a lot like "what hostname should I put in the TLS certificate" – the hostname that was typed.) There may be rDNS involved on Unix systems, but on Windows it's directly just the input.

So if the URL says `https://app2.example1.com`, the server needs a SPN for `HTTP/app2.example.com`, and so on for each URL you have.

> map them to different users?

That is mostly up to you.

> Am I suppose to create a single keytab-file for both app1.example1.com and app2.example1.com or should it be different files?

Traditionally GSSAPI did not have a good way to set the keytab path per-context – software had to set an environment variable for libkrb5 to find the correct keytab.

So if both domains are handled by a single Nginx instance at `lb`, then the default answer is "Single keytab unless the software does the correct thing to allow multiple", whereas if they were handled by different instances at `app1` / `app2`, then it would be simpler to go with separate keytabs.

Looking through the Nginx module's source code, it does not use the GSSAPI "credential store extensions" for keytab handling – it uses a process-wide function – so I believe you will need a single keytab if you choose to handle Kerberos at `lb`.

> Should I run ktpass on each domain controller?

I don't think you need to run it *on a domain controller* specifically at all – it's not any different from all other AD user management tools. You can run on any machine that can *talk to* a domain controller, and you only need to do it once per domain because the changes will automatically sync to all other DCs in that domain.

(What ktpass does at AD level is simply set a new password for the account – Kerberos keys, such as the ones found in keytabs, are derived from the user account's password so there's no special mechanics in generating them.)

> Am I right that I must authorize users at app1.example1.com and app2.example1.com? or, maybe, lb.example1.com should be the point of authorization?

It could be either, but if you have two wholly separate Kerberos realms with no trust between them, I would probably let each app server handle Kerberos for its own realm, without needing any complex configuration on the LB. All the LB needs to do is forward the raw headers without trying to do SPNEGO at all, and the "securely forwarding" part is automatically solved.

Though don't mix up "authenticate" and "authorize" – Kerberos only does authentication; once the client is authenticated as a specific user, checking whether they're authorized to do things is a separate task and it doesn't *really* matter to Kerberos where it's done. (Though, of course, you still need to securely forward the authentication data where it's needed.)

(While AD tickets do carry PAC data useful for authorization, looks like Nginx won't know how to extract that – you'll only get the principal name that they've *authenticated* as, but no group memberships or anything.)

> How my /etc/krb5.conf should look like in this case? Can you provide an example for my configuration?

If Kerberos is to be done on individual app servers (each handling only its own realm), then all you need is to define `default_realm =` under [libdefaults]. Service-specific configuration such as keytabs doesn't need to go into krb5.conf at all.

(I believe AD domains automatically set up SRV records for Kerberos, so I wouldn't bother with defining `kdc =` by hand.)